# Save my MS Word hyphenation settings as default

Tags: ms-word

In MS Word 2003, each time I start editing a document I set specific settings for hyphenation by going through multiple mouse clicks: Tools -> Language -> hyphenation and then I make changes.

This is annoying and repetitive. Is there any way to make these changes once and found them available when editing any other documents?

Thanks

Comment: This is hardly programming related. Did you mean to post this on superuser?

Answer (score 1):

Try searching on your computer for "normal.dot" - make sure you include 'search hidden files or folders' to find it.

'Normal.dot' is the standard blank template for MS word. Open the file, perform the hyphenation changes, and then save the template overwriting the old.

This should apply the affect to all other documents using this template.